# The relation between In-App strings and ASO (App stores Optimization)

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store, app-store-optimization

**My question:** Do Google play and/or Apple App store use the in-app strings when users searching for an app on the app store?

Can I programmatically add keywords in my app? Is there any documentation about this?

### Clarification

Because some of you tried to close this question: I am looking for an answer that related to coding not store listing. `Something that can only be done by a mobile developer` not a marketing guy. here is an [example](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing) of what I am looking for.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a confident answer but I don't think that this type of string matters to ASO. These texts are packaged into the APK/AAB and depend on the localization you are targeting. You could also minify the resources so it won't be an easy task to use them for ASO.

The link you mention is related to exposing intents so the app could be launched from any other place. I think that you could use something like this if you are using some keywords inside the deeplink but it will be more focused on SEO than on ASO.

Disclaimer: As I said, it is just my thought about it and I don't have any proof.

Hope it helps.